# Place Colored Band Over Image/Label + Image/Text Alignment -> JavaScript Titanium Mobile App

Tags: javascript, user-interface, alignment

So I'm trying to place a colored band over an image to make the text more easily read, as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMXLF.jpg

But, I have no idea how to make that appear - this is how it is now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOmMP.jpg. Here's my code for it:

```
var mainTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({data:[], backgroundColor:'transparent'});
var data = [];

var rowNews = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
height:120,
backgroundImage: 'images/News.png',
title:'News',
font:{
    fontFamily: "Helvetica",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
},
color: '#1d1d1d',
backgroundColor:'#b6e2e2',
});
data.push(rowNews);

var rowCup = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
height:120,
backgroundImage: 'images/1MC.png',
title: 'One Million Cups',
font:{
    fontFamily: "Helvetica",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
},
color: '#1d1d1d',
backgroundColor:'#b6e2e2',
});
data.push(rowCup);


var rowEvents = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
height:120,
backgroundImage: 'images/MoreEvents.png',
title:'More Events',
font:{
    fontFamily: "Helvetica",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 18,
},
color: '#1d1d1d',
backgroundColor:'#b6e2e2',
});
data.push(rowEvents);
```

Additionally, I'm having trouble aligning an image with the text, as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz5M2.jpg.

But, it's showing up like this, staggered, shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ1dw.jpg.

Here's my code for this issue:

```
// create scroll view here
var sv = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
contentWidth:'auto',
contentHeight: 'auto',
top: 0,
showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
layout: 'vertical'
}); 

svWin.add(sv);

var lab1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
width: 'fill',
top: 0,
height:120,
backgroundImage: 'images/News.png'
});

var News2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
width: 'fill',
top: 10,
left: 100,
height:65,
font: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: "Helvetica",
    fontWeight: "bold"
},
color: '#0a3f56',
text:'New Business Announced'
});

var img1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
top: 10,
left: 30,
width: 50,
height: 50,
backgroundImage: 'images/MoreEvents.png'
});
```

Obviously, I have omitted some of the code, such as the creation of the windows, adding the objects to scroll view, etc.

I've searched appcelerator docs but there's nothing that specifically addresses this kind of UI setup.

Help would be much appreciated :]

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue: You could create a view for every image you want to show which is the parent of the imageView and the Label. The structure would look like this:

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    //the position of the view
    //the height/width of the view
});

var imageView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: //fill parent
    width: //fill parent
    top: 0,
    image: //your image
});

var Label = Ti.UI.createView({
    bottom: 0,
    height: "20",
    width: //Fill parent
    text: //your Text
    textAlign: //AlignLeft
    //You may need to define the font and the fontSIze
});

view.add(imageView);
view.add(label);
$.yourWIndow.add(view);
```

To make sure your label and image display properly you create a parent view which holds both of them. If you want to make the image clickable you can set the touchEnabled property of the label to true and set the same clickListener to both elements. Another experience I have made is that backgroundImage and dynamically loaded images (from an url) can cause problems on Android so you should avoid using it with dynamic images.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Just gave me the same result and removed the top image for the news page.